reflink==always space usage
I've got a large directory structure (email Maildir), with 705430 files, 1719 directories
Using cp -rP --reflink=always $source $destination uses a fair chunk of space, approx 2–5GB.
This is not a CoW change because the mail volume is an order of magnitude less, and e.g. running du -chs reveals zero change between start-time and end-time of the reflink copy.
So I have two questions:

Is this behaviour expected ? I thought reflink was a zero cost copy, irrespective of directory tree size ?
Is there a more efficient way to do this ? Should I consider LVM snapshots for example ?

This is XFS on Debian Bookworm.

how many files are we talking here? how many directories? Also, to rule out coreutils bugs: when you run strace -o /tmp/cp.strace cp -rP --reflink=always $source $destinaton (you can abort after a second), does grep CLONE /tmp/cp.strace show a lot of ioctl( …, BTRFS_IOC_CLONE or FICLONE, …) = 0?

(to figure out how many files there are, assuming you're in bash: shopt -s dotglob globstar; allfiles=( **/* ); echo ${#allfiles[@]}

@MarcusMüller 705430 files, 1719 directories


Is this behaviour expected ?

No, and I can't reproduce it on my system (XFS, Linux 6.7.5, coreutils with fedora patches 9.4).

I thought reflink was a zero cost copy, irrespective of directory tree size ?

It should reuse all the data blocks, but clearly, the file names, metadata and directory structures need to be stored, so the metadata usage of the file system does need to increase. By 2 GB? Not for this amount of files.

Is there a more efficient way to do this ? Should I consider LVM snapshots for example ?

Snapshots will not save you space on making a copy. They might allow you to go back to an earlier state, but honestly, reflinking seems to be the thing that should work.
